# "What" is our universe expanding into

Tags: grammar

"What is it expanding into?" or "What is our universe expanding into?" are some of the headlines I have read but I was wondering why the questions do not start with "Where"?

Comment: Both are possible. 'Where' asks about a place or location; 'what' asks about the nature of what is in that place.

Answer (score 1):

The word **what** implies a much richer range of possibilities than **where**. Also, **where** does not work well in this context.

If you wanted to begin the question with  **where**, you might ask:
**Where is our universe expanding?** but that might mean which areas of the universe are expanding; it's not idiomatic to add **into** in this context. While **to** is a possible final preposition, **what** is more effective.

The question seems to mean: **What is it beyond the limits of the universe into which the universe is expanding?**

The answer, of course, (if there is anywhere beyond the limits of the universe, if the universe has any limits) is outside the scope of this site.